# How do I prevent the cursor going up instead of down when I press enter in an e-mail while using an iMac

Tags: email, civicase

Our organisation is using CiviCrm 4.4.8. And we use Civicases a lot. Our users that login to our CiviCrm system using an iMac have trouble typing their e-mail (on a case) as each time when they press enter the cursor goes up instead of down. 
Can any one help us solving this issue, I am sure we are not the only one who has bumped into this issue.

Looking forward to your response.

Comment: I don't have such an old copy of CiviCRM handy, but when I'm looking at the "Open Case" screen in CiviCRM, I don't see a place to enter an email.  So I think I'm looking at the wrong screen.  Could you please edit your question to make it clear which screen has this problem?

Comment: Jon the email is under Case Roles on Manage Case - you can click on a mail icon in there to send an email and file it on the case.

Answer (score 1):

Under Administer - Customize Data and Screens - Display Preferences, there's a choice for WYSIWYG editor. Try changing it to something else and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: I've seen this behaviour using WYSIWYG editors. I don't know whether its specific to the browser being used, or the WYSIWYG editor itself.